# Warning: is_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

When i run magento command i get this error.

```
[Exception]                                                                  
  Warning: is_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in   
  /opt/lampp/htdocs/mij_new_design/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/  
  File.php on line 512
```

Answer (score 7):

**Try this :**

```
rm -rf var/cache var/log var/page_cache var/view_preprocessed
```

More detail : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10878

Answer (score 2):

No need to delete particular folder just run this command :-

**Just One time**

```
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*   == Clear cache 
rm -rf generated/* == Clear generated classes
```

Please do not run

```
rm -rf var/*
```

Because it will removed your database backup and other module log files.

Comment: For second line, added `-r` recursive flag since hierarchy of files existed in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by deleting content under the `var/view_preprocessed/` and `generated/` directories. I then ran the commands(in this order):

---

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

---

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

---

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`